# What are the finite etale covers of a Calabi-Yau variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm interested in the etale fundamental group of a Calabi-Yau variety. The definition of a Calabi-Yau variety that I use, is a smooth projective variety over field $k=\bar k$ with trivial canonical bundle plus $H^i(X, \mathcal O_X)=0$ for $i=1,...,dim X -1$. I assume for the moment that the base field is of characteristic 0. If necessary, I could also assume $k=\mathbb C$.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**:

I met (a version of) Beauville-Bogomolov decomposition theorem in Thm 6.1 *On the geometry of hyoersurfaces of low degrees in the projective space* by Debarre. It says:

> For a smooth projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb C$ with vanishing
>   first $\mathbb R$-Chern class, there exists a finite etale cover which
>   is isomorphic to the product of
>
> - abelian varieties, or
> - simply connected variety $Y$ of dim $\ge3$ with $H^i(Y,\mathcal O_Y)=0$ for $0<i<n$,
> - simply connected holomorphic sympletic varieties.

(Note that the definition there for a CY variety is different from the one I take). But because of my weak background in complex geoemtry, I could not deduce anything special for $X$ being a Calabi-Yau variety... In particular, I would guess "Any Calabi–Yau manifold has a finite cover that is the product of a torus and a simply-connected Calabi–Yau manifold" (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold/%22Wikipedia%22)) is a consequence of this decomposition theorem, but I could not work it out.

As I was looking through the literature (they might have different definitions for a Calabi-Yau!), I am aware that under such a definition, a Calabi-Yau might not be simply connected. And at the same time, most of the examples that people are concerned have finite or even trivial (topological) fundamental group (for a 3-fold with infinite fundamental group, see [Oguiso-Sakurai](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9909175.pdf) and [Kanazawa](http://archive.ymsc.tsinghua.edu.cn/pacm_download/188/8223-CalabiYauthreefoldswithinfinite.pdf)). So my question is what does the finite etale covers of a Calabi-Yau look like. More precisely,

- Is there an if and only if criterion for a Calabi-Yau to be simply connected? In our definition, dimension 2 are precisely the K3 surfaces, which are always simply connected. So the next is Calabi-Yau 3-fold. Can people say something at least for some special types of Calabi-Yau 3-fold?
- If the fundamental group is non-trivial, what could be the possible finite etale covers? In the decomposition theorem stated above, it only asserts the existence part of a good decomposition. In other words, not every finite etale cover is of that form. Some questions on this aspects include: what is the criterion for a finite etale cover of a Calabi-Yau to be still a Calabi-Yau? What can be the quotient of a Calabi-Yau by a finite group? For the latter , I found this [Kollar-Larsen](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701466.pdf) paper, but our definition for Calabi-Yau is stronger than the one they use. Can people say something more with our stronger definition?

I apologize if I missed out any results that are already written in the literature above. Different definitions of Calabi-Yau make me dizzy and maybe it's always better to get a thread from experts.

In the end, I would be glad to know any introductory notes to Calabi-Yau that use more the algebraic language.

Comment: Have you heard of the Beauville-Bogomolov decomposition theorem? I'm not sure this theorem gives you exactly what you want, but it might get you started over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: With this definition of a CY variety, there are non-simply connected CY varieties.

Comment: What kind of things would you like to know about these groups?

Comment: Thank you for all the comments! I have re-edited my question according to them.

Comment: @user31480 Just a short comment, as I think there is a little bit of confusion. If $X$ is an algebraic variety with infinite (etale) fundamental group, then every finite etale cover of $X$ has an infinite (etale) fundamental group. However, if $X$ is an algebraic variety with finite (topological) fundamental group, it could happen that $X$ has a trivial etale fundamental group.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thanks for your comment! The first statement is OK for me (because the etale $\pi_1$ of the covering space is a subgroup of that of the base, and their quotient set is finite). For the second statement: in the smooth case, since the profinite completion of a finite group (not necessarily commutative) is isomorphic to the group itself, such kind of phenomenon should not appear. So I think you're thinking of some non-smooth example. Could you please specify? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user31480 I made a small (very unfortunate) typo in my last sentence. It should have been "If $X$ is an algebraic variety with INFINITE (topological) fundamental group, it could happen that $X$ has a trivial etale fundamental group."

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Could you give an example or a reference? Thanks.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126489/is-there-non-simple-connected-projective-varietyover-c-with-trivial-etale-fund